# How to write exponent in racket?

Tags: racket, exponent

Using `(x^4)` or (^ x 4) giving an error message. Is there some functions for exponent than simply using `(* x x x x)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the primitive function `expt` (see [reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=expt#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._expt%29%29)):

```
(expt x 4)    ;  = x⁴
```

Answer (score 2):

If you forget `expt`, you can use:

```
(for/product ((i 4))  x)
```

It's easier than writing `(* x x x x)` for larger values.